# pass params in angular get httpclient request

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I would set data via headers or params and use a get method.

I have created my service.

```
public openFile(pathFile) {
  let url='/download/';
  let mockUrl; 
  let file= new HttpHeaders();
  file=pathFile
  return this.httpClient.get(url,file);
}
```

The problem in VS code I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'
```

And when I try to run the service, server gives me this error:

```
{timestamp: 1524743028303, status: 400, error: "Bad Request", exception: "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException", message: "Required String parameter 'pathFile' is not present", …}
```

Comment: You want to Hit `GET` request with params ?

Comment: yes, I would pass params on Httpheaders or HttpParams

Comment: I think request should be POST and you need to send data as body params

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I missed another error as I copied your example and only changed one line.

Have a look at the line with httpClient.get. You don't pass in the headers directly, but you pass in an object which has a headers field.

```
public openFile(pathFile) {
    let url='/download/';
    let headers= new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('file', pathFile);
    return this.httpClient.get(url, { headers: headers });
}
```

As @infodev mentioned in a comment you can leave out the HttpHeaders class. Then it would look something like this:

```
public openFile(pathFile) {
    let url='/download/';
    return this.httpClient.get(url, { headers: { file: pathFile } });
}
```

Comment: In angular 5.2 can directly ser the header object in the get request without declaring a new HttpHeaders() ?

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. But you can also use HttpHeaders. But thanks to your comment I think I found another problem ;)